# Fail to load react nodejs app in AKS(Azure Kubenetics Service) but successfully in local docker container

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a react nodejs application and it works fine running in local in the docker container, however, I am having trouble deploying it to AKS. I am not sure where my configuration gets wrong in AKS manifest file and I would appreciate your help!

I have one dockerfile for frontend(react) and one dockerfile for backend(nodejs). I also have a docker-compose.yml file. The file structure looks like below:

```
--api(dir for backend)
 --dockerfile
--my-app(dir for frontend)
 --dockerfile
--dockercompose.yml
```

My docker file for frontend is as below:

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /my-app
COPY . .
RUN npm install && npm run build
EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My dockerfile for the backend is as below:

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /api
COPY ./package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3080

CMD ["node", "--require",  "./tracing.js",  "./server.js"]
```

My docker-compose file is as below:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app-backend:
    build: ./api
    container_name: app-backend
    ports:
        - "3080:3080"

  app-frontend:
    depends_on:
      - app-backend
    build: ./my-app
    container_name: app-frontend
    ports:
        - "3000:3000"
    tty: true
```

This is how my frontend package.json look like:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://app-backend:3080",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

My AKS manifest file look like below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app-backend
        image: danpoc0acr.azurecr.io/react-nodejs-aks-app-backend:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3080

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-backend
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3080
  selector:
    app: app-backend
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app-frontend
        image: danpoc0acr.azurecr.io/react-nodejs-aks-app-frontend:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-frontend
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 3000
  selector:
    app: app-frontend
```

After I ran kubectl apply -f manifest.yml, it shows me below in CLI.
[image]

I can also see below in AKS, but if I try to load external IP in browser with or without port 3000, it never loads. I wonder if my manifest file is missing something. Or is there a way to debug where goes wrong?
[image]

Comment: Can you try accessing it with port 30014?

Comment: No, it is not working either.